# IQueryable difference between .NET 6 and 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

TL;DR: Disable `Nullable` on entities which are not manually configured using `IEntityTypeConfiguration` when upgrading.

I am currently in the process of upgrading our ASP.Net Core app to .NET 7. In theory this should work flawless since there aren't any changes that could potentially cause issues.

But after some testing I found out that a lot of our database interactions failed with weird behaviour. Right now I have on entity in my database, when running this following code I get two completely different results:

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

**.NET 6**: `count = 1` and `items.Count = 1`

**.NET 7**: `count = 1` and `items.Count = 0`.

The query used is this:

```
var types = Entities.Include(p => p.Template).AsQueryable();
return await types.OrderBy(request.SortBy, request.OrderBy)
     .PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);
```

The `OrderBy` method is an extension method which uses LINQ's `OrderBy` but with a property name as input (view [here](https://gist.github.com/Skyppid/4dfcb5cd75c89115b70b105b9c886621) if relevant). `Entities` is the `DbSet` itself.

Can someone explain to me why this does change between .NET versions? I did **NOT** upgrade EF to version 7 yet. It's still *6.0.12*.

I checked the breaking changes and couldn't find anything about changes to queryables or enumerables.

Comment: Do you have defined Global QueryFilter?

Comment: Nope, not really. I just added one line the post, I forgot the initial query on it, but still it's nothing that would explain a different behaviour when using `Count` and `ToList`.

Comment: Usually this problem appear when you have defined **required** navigation but it is has no records in database. In this case EF generates `INNER JOIN`, which filters out main records.

Comment: Yeah okay, but why would it work on the same EF version under .NET 6, but once I upgrade to .NET 7 it starts to break? Shouldn't that kinda rule out EF/DB being the culprit?

Comment: Compare SQL, it what you have to check at start.  Why it happened, I don't  know, probably something changed with default conventions.

Comment: The SQL is absolutely identical. Not a single difference between the two of them. Gotta be an issue under the hood as it seems.

Comment: Missed that you have Eager Loading. Try `AsSplitQuery()` - it uses different algorithm for retrieving entities. Anyway looks like a serious bug.

Comment: So far I can tell by source stepping that under .NET 6 it directly iterates on it and reads data while under .NET 7 it first tries to checks some kind of compiled query cache and does a lot of other stuff with eventually ending up having no data. `AsSplitQuery` does not fix it, though.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You were right. I overlooked the JOIN statement. Turns out this was actually an issue with nullable being enabled. Thus most entities where configured wrong. As usually the bug was in front of the computer.

Comment: Yeah, the fr..ing NRTs enabled by default. And EF Core "taking advantage" of that. If you want a good advice, always put `#nullable disable` at the top of your entity model code files.

Comment: I just disabled Nullable on project level for our Domain project until I fully configured the database entities. Wasn't the best design choice to just let EF do it. But yeah, learned that the hard way.